# DNS PTR lookup deprecated?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, ptr-record

When I use dmarcanalyzer to check my domain I get the message:

> Warning : You shouldn't use PTR lookups as they are deprecated

My record looks like this:
`v=spf1 ptr:samplemail.com ip4:191.13.174.145 ip4:191.13.174.146 a:samplemail.com ip4:81.211.16.14 ~all`

What part exactly is deprecated? I tried Googling but all I get are sites where I can do a PTR record lookup or unclear (to me) examaples.

Comment: It is not the DNS PTR lookup that is deprecated, but rather its use in conjunction with SPF records. :-)

Comment: See here: https://dmarcian.com/ptr-mechanisms-in-spf-records/

Comment: Ok, so this works now `v=spf1 ip4:191.13.174.145 ~all`, however I tried Googling how to add a PTR record but found no real examples. From your 1st comment it still looks like I need one right? What format does it have?